# Installing WiFi driver for slackware Linux

Tags: linux, wifi, intel, slackware, iwlwifi

I have the latest `Slackware` with `Linux kernel 4.4.14` installed. The system has been giving me issues with network since installation. I have `Intel Wireless-AC 9560` Wi-Fi card, which works fine in Windows 10, (as expected), but isn't working heck, isn't even showing up in slackware when I type `iwconfig` or `ifconfig`. `lspci` recognises it though. I downloaded the drivers for it from the Intel official driver [site](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html). However, copying the ucode images to the `/lib/firmware` directory is somehow not working. What are my alternatives?

P.S. It should be noted that [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78600/wireless-on-slackware) doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the GUI is also broken... ok 
Can you try and run startx command as root? to see if the GUI is working as root? if yes then go to your home account delete all .serverauthXXX and .Xauthority files as root.

Also did you install Slackware as a full install on the installation steps?

Can you please also give a try to install the exton kernel
https://news.softpedia.com/news/you-can-now-run-a-custom-linux-4-14-2-kernel-on-your-slackware-pc-here-s-how-518751.shtml
to see if the newest kernel will find your card

If I was you I will give one more try to reinstall slackware from the start and follow the first step the one I told you the chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.networkmanager for your wifi card (do a reboot after this command)
Then follow the instructions
https://docs.slackware.com/slackware:beginners_guide
1) to add user
2) to select mirror
3) update Slackware

I dont know what you did exactly I am just guessing. Slackware is my best operating system and you should give one more try and you will find your way. I was in your position too when I was trying to do my first Slackware installation. It was a nightmare :) for me too but I learned a lot of things using this particular operating system. Good luck my friend

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do the following
go to as root
/etc/rc.d

then type the command
chmod +x rc.networkmanager

reboot and see if the wifi icon now appears on your system tray (kde or to xfce) to choose your wifi network